# AppEngine Datastore: Hierarchical queries

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

If you're dealing with a hierarchy of records, where most of the keys have ancestors, will you have to create a chain of all of the keys before you can retrieve a leaf?

Example (in Go):

`rootKey = datastore.NewKey(ctx, "EntityType", "", id1, nil)
secondGenKey = datastore.NewKey(ctx, "EntityType", "", id2, rootKey)
thirdGenKey = datastore.NewKey(ctx, "EntityType", "", id3, rootKey)`

How do you get the record described by `thirdGenKey` without having to declare the keys for all of the levels of the hierarchy above it?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get an individual entity, its key must be globally unique - this is enforced through each entity key being unique within its entity group. The ancestor path forms an intrinsic part of the entity key for this reason.

So, the only way to get a single entity *with strong consistency* is to specify its ancestor path. This can be done either with a get-by-key or with an ancestor query.

If you don't know the full ancestor path, your only option is to query on a property of the entity, but bear in mind that:

- this may not be unique within your application
- you will be subject to eventual consistency.

Comment: That's what I'm confirming. So, if your hierarchy is comprised of many ancestral levels, you'll need to construct a key with an ID and no ancestor, another key with its ID and the first key for this ancestor, another key with its ID and the second key for this ancestor, etc.., all of the way down until you're at the right level to access your principal record, correct? In other words, if you have a record at level N, then you'll have to construct a chain of N keys in order to retrieve it with strong consistency, correct?

Comment: @DustinOprea, that is correct. Your comment on strong consistency is misleading though, all lookups (explicit gets by key) are strongly consistent, it has nothing to do with key ancestor which must be present. Eventual consistency comes in to play when you do a query (0-n entities returned) without bounding the query to a single ancestor (entity-group).

Comment: @DanMcGrath Yes.. It's the presence of ancestors that make it SC, but you'd need the full chain to descend far enough. Thanks, Dan.

Comment: @DustinOprea for lookups/gets it is *not* the presence of ancestors that make it strongly consistent - they all SC, ancestor or not. I just want to make that clear. It's an important distinction.

Comment: I'm referring to the retrieval, on this side of the API. If no ancestor is used then retrieval may not get the latest version. Please confirm.

Comment: @tx802 Also, just to clarify, can you search over a key without specifying an ancestor and potentially just have to deal with multiple results (one for every entity-group that contains a key that matching the ID), or, as you said, you can only fallback on the entities-by-kind index?

Answer (score 1):

To supplement tx802's answer:

If you want to load an entity by key, you *need* its key. If the key is such a key that has a parent, in order to form / create the key, you also need the parent key to be created prior. The parent key *is* part of the key, just like the numeric ID or the string name.

Looking from the implementation perspective: [datastore.Key](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/datastore#Key) is a struct:

```
type Key struct {
    kind      string
    stringID  string
    intID     int64
    parent    *Key
    appID     string
    namespace string
}
```

In order to construct a `Key` which has a parent, you must construct the parent key too, recursively. If you're finding it too verbose to always create the key hierarchy, you can create a helper function for it.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume all keys use the same entity name, and we only use numeric IDs. It may look like this:

```
func createKey(ctx context.Context, entity string, ids ...int) (k *datastore.Key) {
    for _, id := range ids {
        k = datastore.NewKey(ctx, entity, "", id, k)
    }
    return
}
```

With this helper function, your example is reduced to this:

```
k2 := createKey(ctx, "EntityType", id1, id2)
k3 := createKey(ctx, "EntityType", id1, id3)
```

Comment: Thank you for the further clarification. It seems like this model doesn't really accommodate homogenous/recursive trees of the same entity-type. For example, in my case I have a large tree of classifiers (where the ancestor of all children in a row is the parent), but there's no practical way to 1) store an identifier that represents the parent as a key on the record, nor 2) to reference one of these classifiers from another record (because the IDs are only unique to the ancestor, so the recursive/nested ancestor/parent key would also have to be stored as a property). (Continued...)

Comment: ...In the interest of being immediately consistent, of course. Naturally, I could create a globally unique key and use that for lookups/references, but then  it's just eventually consistent. It seems like this model is most convenient for when you have several discrete ancestors readily at hand with which to build the compound key (a dynamic number of levels isn't as feasible) and/or you only just have a handful of heterogenous, nested entity types, e.g. company->user->invoice. Thoughts? I appreciate your insights. I'm trying to figure out the patterns here.

Comment: @DustinOprea There are multiple "practical" ways to store key information. One option would be to have a property of `Key` type, and the value of that property can be any `Key` value, including keys which have parents. Another option would be to store the list of IDs in a property (given you only use IDs and not string names); you could even choose to store them in a single string like `"id1,id2"`, or as a multi-value property (slice), like `[id1, id2]`; and having these IDs only, you can reconstruct the `Key` should you need that, e.g. with the `createKey()` function posted in the answer.

Comment: I've previously tried a "Key"-type property, but I had issues. I figured it was just inconsistency in the documentation (like where the website says Datastore can support the whole spectrum of integer sizes but the code only support int64). I'll have to give it another shot.

Comment: @DustinOprea See [Datastore reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference): _"Valid value types are: ... `*Key`, ..."_. I assume you forgot the `*` to make it a pointer type.

Comment: I tried both, but I can go back to it now with fresh eyes.